# Select element in XML, same node name different attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have the following XML and i need to fill it with some data from an array.
Problem is it has 3 nodes with the name "contact" but each of them have a different attribute.
I tried using Xpath but i didnt not managed to make it work kept getting errors.
I think it probably is a syntax error.

sample of the xml

```
<command>
<create>
<domain:create xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0
domain-1.0.xsd">
<domain:name>0000</domain:name>
<domain:period unit="y">2</domain:period>
<domain:ns>
<domain:hostObj>0000</domain:hostObj>
</domain:ns>
<domain:registrant>0000</domain:registrant>
<domain:contact type="tech">000</domain:contact>
<domain:contact type="admin">000</domain:contact>
<domain:contact type="billing">000</domain:contact>
<domain:authInfo>
<domain:pw>000</domain:pw>
</domain:authInfo>
</domain:create>
</create>
<clTRID>ABC:ics-forth:1079691187887</clTRID>
</command>
</epp>
```

And below my code

```
        $p2xml = new SimpleXmlElement($p2xmlf);
        foreach ($p2xml->command->create as $entry2)
        {
            $namespaces = $entry2->getNameSpaces(true);
            $dc = $entry2->children($namespaces['domain']);
            $dc->create->name = $domain_fields['name'];
            $dc->create->ns->hostObj = $domain_fields['ns1'];
            $dc->create->ns->hostObj = $domain_fields['ns2'];
            $dc->create->registrant = $domain_fields['registrant'];
            $dc->create->contact = $domain_fields['contact']; <-- problem here
            $dc->create->contact = $domain_fields['contact']; <-- problem here
            $dc->create->contact = $domain_fields['contact']; <-- problem here
            $dc->create->authInfo->pw = $domain_fields['pw']; 
            $oxml = $p2xml->asXML();
```

Tried replacing contact with //contact[@type=['tech'] and some others but i'm stuck

Comment: //contact[@type=['tech'] is not valid XPath. There should not be brackets around the value of the attribute, and there is no closing bracket for the attribute. The fact that there are an unequal number of open and close brackets should be a tip-off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that PHP API accepts XPath, but if it does, the XPath you would want to use to select each of the three elements would be:

```
//contact[@type='tech']
//contact[@type='admin']
//contact[@type='billing']
```